# How to change the post slug with WordPresss functions?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

After a post is created, it looks like:

```
https://www.example.com/mypost/
```

Now I want to use a WordPress built-in function to change 'mypost' to 'yourpost'. How to do so? I cannot find such a function on Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the slug in WordPress, you can use the `wp_update_post` function along with the `wp_insert_post` function. Here's how you can do it:

```
<?php
// First, get the post ID based on the post URL
$post_url = 'https://www.example.com/mypost/';
$post_id = url_to_postid( $post_url );

// If post ID is found
if ( $post_id ) {
    // Get the post object
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    
    // Update the post's slug to 'yourpost'
    $post->post_name = 'yourpost';
    
    // Update the post in the database
    wp_update_post( $post );
    
    echo "Slug updated successfully!";
} else {
    echo "Post not found!";
}
?>
```

Hopefully this will fix your problem.
Happy Coding :)